# Angular 11 is not running ngcc

Tags: angular, ivy

I have an old Angular application, which I have upgraded from Angular 9 to Angular 11. (It had many stable upgrades throughout the years, starting from Angular 2)

My problem is, that the `ngcc` is not running `ng build`:

```
$ ng build
    'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: node_modules/ngx-device-detector/index.d.ts:3:23 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

3     static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/public_api.d.ts:22:53 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

22     static forRoot(config?: TranslateModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/public_api.d.ts:26:54 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

26     static forChild(config?: TranslateModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I really need it, as you can see that some of the packages has [old dependency issues](https://next.angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers) which ngcc can solve. I thought that as we are using Ivy, running it will be part of the `build` by default. I was able to run the command manually as `npx ngcc`:

```
forest@forest:~/....$ npx ngcc
Compiling @angular/core : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : esm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : main as umd
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : esm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : main as umd
Compiling @angular/common : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-translate/core : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-translate/core : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : fesm2015 as esm2015

...
```

and after that the app runs just as intended:

```
ng build
    'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.
                                                                                                                                                        
Initial Chunk Files | Names         |      Size                                                                                                         
vendor.js           | vendor        |  14.23 MB                                                                                                         
main.js             | main          |   4.31 MB                                                                                                         
styles.css          | styles        | 637.39 kB
polyfills-es5.js    | polyfills-es5 | 583.94 kB
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 148.32 kB
runtime.js          | runtime       |   6.15 kB

                    | Initial Total |  19.88 MB

Build at: 2021-01-26T13:06:31.502Z - Hash: 2340989d60fecfe588df - ....
```

Something might be blocking it, but I cannot find the root cause. Any ideas what can be the problem?

My Angular version:

```
$ ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.1.1
Node: 12.3.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.1
@angular-devkit/core            8.3.28
@angular-devkit/schematics      8.3.28
@angular/cli                    11.1.1
@angular/http                   7.2.16
@schematics/angular             8.3.28
@schematics/update              0.803.28
rxjs                            6.6.0
typescript                      4.0.5
webpack                         4.43.0
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "eets-frontend",
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^11.1.0",
  ...
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "latest",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.3",
    "@commitlint/config-angular": "latest",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^1.1",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^4.1",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.44",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/jszip": "^3.1.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "audit-ci": "latest",
    "axe-core": "^3.4",
    "babel-loader": "latest",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.0",
    "codecov-json-to-lcov": "^1.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "commitlint-config-jira": "latest",
    "commitlint-plugin-jira-rules": "latest",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "cypress": "^4.8.0",
    "cypress-autorecord": "^1.1",
    "cypress-axe": "^0.6",
    "cypress-plugin-snapshots": "^1.2",
    "datalist-polyfill": "^1.24.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0",
    "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.5.2",
    "jsonlint-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "koa": "^2.12.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-router": "^8.0.8",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.8",
    "markdownlint-cli": "^0.22",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^8",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "nyc": "^15.0",
    "pa11y": "^5",
    "prettier": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "protractor-istanbul-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5",
    "stylelint": "^13.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "latest",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "latest",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "latest",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.10",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.6",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "latest",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "latest",
    "tslint-consistent-codestyle": "latest",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "wait-on": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "js-base64": "2.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not upgrade between more than 1 major version. It will help you track down problems to 1 Version, instead of 2 or more.

Comment: I have upgraded from ng9->ng10 first as was suggested by the official guide. Then from ng10->ng11

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was that an another `tsconfig` file was overwriting the root's definitions, and turned off ivy and ngcc altogether.

`sr5c/tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  ...
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything to Ivy, this is simply a tsconfig that extends another one... I'm confused as to how this is a solution to anything. To be clear, the "extends" property doesn't "overwrite" the root, it "extends" it like class inheritance. Any properties you don't define are inherited from the extended parent.

Answer (score 9):

you can try:

1. add these commands to `package.json` in *scripts*:

   ```json
     {
       "scripts": {
         // ...
         "ngcc": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser main module --async false --first-only",
        "postinstall": "npm run ngcc",
      }
    }
   ```
2. delete the *node_modules* folder and then install the dependencies again.

   > run `rm -fr node_modules` and then `npm install`.

this example is an idea if you use *CI*, otherwise you can just use `"postinstall":"ngcc"`

[Ivy and Universal / App shell](https://v12.angular.io/guide/ivy#ivy-and-universalapp-shell)